# Is “Karotte” a slang term for “idiot”?

Tags: meaning, slang

In this clip (1:00 onwards) Karl-Heinz Rummenigge twice uses what sounds to me like “Karotten” to mean “idiots”. Have I heard this correctly? I hadn’t come across the word being used in this sense before. Is there a more nuanced meaning than simply “idiot” (perhaps referencing the shape of a carrot)?

[DW news clip about banner protest at German football match](https://twitter.com/dw_sports/status/1233889687841824768?s=21)

The context here is a news story in which a Bundesliga match was halted, and all but abandoned after one team’s fans displayed a banner insulting the opposing team’s owner. The FC Bayern coach Rummenigge gave his thoughts about those fans to the press after the match.

Here’s my attempt at a transcription of what Rummenigge said:

> Ich schäme mich zutiefst aus Sicht des FC Bayern für diese **Karotten**, und ich kann nur einst sagen es ist den Moment gekommen jetzt spätestens Heute, wo die ganze Bundesliga, der DFB, die DFL gemeinsam Schrittes gegen diese **Karotten** vorgehen müssen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rummenigge sprach von Chaoten (Personen die Chaos stiften), nicht Karotten:

> Die ganze Bundesliga, die DFL und der DFB müssen zusammenstehen und
>   gegen diese Chaoten vorgehen. Wir haben viel zu lange die Augen
>   zugemacht.

[Rummenigge auf sport1.de](https://www.sport1.de/fussball/bundesliga/2020/02/rummenigge-verurteilt-hopp-schmaehungen-stimmen-zu-bayern-spiel-in-hoffenheim)